# Flask traceback only shows external libraries

Tags: python, flask

I'm running a Flask app and get the following error message:

```
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: ******
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Dec/2022 12:21:53] "GET /authorization/****/authorize HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Dec/2022 12:21:53] "GET /authorization/****/test HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1844, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2340, in process_response
    self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 409, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))  # type: ignore
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/itsdangerous/serializer.py", line 207, in dumps
    payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/itsdangerous/url_safe.py", line 53, in dump_payload
    json = super().dump_payload(obj)
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/itsdangerous/serializer.py", line 169, in dump_payload
    return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj, **self.serializer_kwargs))
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/json/tag.py", line 308, in dumps
    return dumps(self.tag(value), separators=(",", ":"))
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 124, in dumps
    return app.json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/json/provider.py", line 230, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/json/provider.py", line 122, in _default
    raise TypeError(f"Object of type {type(o).__name__} is not JSON serializable")
```

I don't understand why it shows only lines from external libraries. What could be the reason it doesn't show which line in my code caused the program to stop?

When I try to replicate the error in a small app (code below), it does show the line number.

```
import flask
import json
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "####"

@app.route("/")
def index():
    json.dumps(json)  # Line that causes error

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("localhost", 8080, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what happened. The core of the error is

```
File "******/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 409, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))  # type: ignore
```

This doesn't happen anywhere in my code, but rather somewhere later where Flask does things. And the thing it is doing is [saving the session](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/910179f9b0999685f5594284f0dc1577392034bd/src/flask/sessions.py#L409). If an error occurs there, it's because I put some improper thing in my session data. So the solution was to make sure that everything I save to `flask.session` is JSON serializable.